# DCMTK question error: libc.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ipad

I am trying to write simple dcmtk application I adeed the following header

```
#include <dcmtk/config/osconfig.h> 
#include <dcmtk/dcmimgle/dcmimage.h>
```

it give the error error: libc.h: No such file or directory

I use xcode and mac os snow leopard

any suggestin please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to compile for iOS?  When you setup DCMTK to generate the appropriate build files, add this line to CMakeLists.txt before you run CMake:

```
SET(HAVE_LIBC_H FALSE)
```

I'd place this line in the configuration file where the C/C++ flags are set for the Darwin OS.  That should help you eliminate this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I have posted to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996157/linker-error-in-objective-c/12742545#12742545).

In /usr/include from the root folder there are some headers available. libc.h is one of them. I included it in my iPhoneOS SDK's usr/include folder. And it doesn't complain anymore. Figure out where to get it and add it, or remove dependencies on it.

HTH.