# linker error in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I use external libraries while adding them to my code for ipad application(Device debug)

it give me this error error: libc.h: No such file or directory

any suggestion how to fix that

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to show us your link command line, but it seems to be that you have something like:

```
ld -o myApp file1.o file2.o libc.h
```

And libc.h is not present in the directory the linker is looking for your objects.  In fact, based on its name, I'm guessing it's a header and not an object file anyway, so having it in that directory wouldn't get you any farther.

If you can explain better what you're trying to do and how you're going about it, I might be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: I use DCMTK library and at one of its header it use #include libc.h which not found and raise error

Comment: That's not a link error, then - it's a compile time error.  Make sure your project's include paths include the location where that header exists.  I'm not familiar with `libc.h` - did it come with your library?

Comment: No it's not related to the library

Comment: @Ali, then you need to figure out where to get it and add it to your project (or how to remove the dependencies on it) - it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the solution to this, can you post it here, because I have the same issue and I see it has been a year since this question has been asked. I cannot post comments for some reason so I added this as an answer, not intended.

And is this -> [DCMTK question error: libc.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991583/dcmtk-question-error-libc-h-no-such-file-or-directory) the solution to your question? You have the same question posted here. Please mark it if this is the answer.

**EDIT** : In /usr/include from the root folder there are some headers available. libc.h is one of them. I included it in my iPhoneOS SDK's usr/include folder. And it doesn't complain anymore. Basically, what ^ Carl Norum said was right, "figure out where to get it and add it, or remove dependencies on it". The problem is resolved.